# Move OpenCart front page only from a subdirectory

Tags: opencart

I have installed OpenCart in a subdirectory (ex: www.example.com/shop/) but I would like to move/show the OpenCart front page as my main website front page.
Can it be done, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> RedirectMatch 301 ^/shop/$ http://www.example.com/

in your htaccess file

```
#This is a permanent redirect
RedirectMatch 301 ^/shop/.*$ http://www.example.com/
#This is a temporary redirect
RedirectMatch 302 ^/shop/.*$ http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: your code will not work as Opencart has `config.php` files which contain those paths.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy replies. Just to check, I only want to move the front page and keep the rest in the subdirectory. Cheers ;o)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the paths in 2 `config.php` files. First, the config.php file from main Opencart directory and the second config.php file from admin folder.

**Example:**

from this:

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.example.com/shop/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.example.com/shop/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/user/opencart/shop/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/user/opencart/shop/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/user/opencart/shop/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/user/opencart/shop/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/user/opencart/shop/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/user/opencart/shop/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/user/opencart/shop/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/user/opencart/shop/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/user/opencart/shop/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/user/opencart/shop/system/logs/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'opencart');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
?>
```

to this:

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.example.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.example.com/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/user/opencart/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/user/opencart/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/user/opencart/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/user/opencart/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/user/opencart/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/user/opencart/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/user/opencart/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/user/opencart/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/user/opencart/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/user/opencart/system/logs/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'opencart');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
?>
```

Where `/home/user/opencart/` is the fullpath of Opencart installation.
And notice I removed `/shop` from each path.

Also, if you have a `.htaccess` file, you will have to change the `RewriteBase`:

from

```
RewriteBase /shop/
```

to

```
RewriteBase /
```